# Extract function of raster package gives incorrect values from Chelsa layers

Tags: r, raster

I made a stack of Chelsa climatic layers (1981 - 2010; bioclimatic layers), and tried to extract values using occurrence records. But, I am getting wrong values.

Loading rasters

```
library (raster)
library (sp)

layers <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/DELL/OneDrive/Documents", 
                      pattern='.tif$', all.files= T, full.names= TRUE)
allrasters <- lapply(layers, raster)
bio_layers<-stack(allrasters)
```

nr

```
longitude latitude
-58.93127 -34.19912
-58.86730 -33.4797
-60.64690 -32.0161
-60.16690 -32.635
-60.57160 -31.67717
-57.51700 -25.335
```

```
coordinates(nr)<-c("longitude", "latitude")
ex<-extract(bio_layers[[1]], nr, df = T)
```

ex

```
1 2900
2 2908
3 2917
4 2913
5 2918
6 2956
```

The result that I showed here is for annual mean temperature (bio1). These values are not correct. When I use QGIS for extracting values, it works well. May I know where I am going wrong ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extracted values are perfectly right. I have seen the [CHELSA V2.1: Technical specification](https://chelsa-climate.org/wp-admin/download-page/CHELSA_tech_specification_V2.pdf), **7.1. Climatologies**. The values are scaled. So, inorder to have the correct values, you have to do

```
bio1 = bio_layers[[1]]*0.1-273.15
```

If I do it, then the values will be

```
1 16.85
2 17.65
3 18.55
4 18.15
5 18.65
6 22.45
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. It clears a lot of confusion. We need to do this calculation, only if want to get the exact values, am I right??. For employing these rasters as variables in modeling niches, we need not bother about these scaling, am I right ??